# Scala factorial method (that is "!") : removing the dot operator?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I managed to define a new operator for Integer in scala : the "!" factorial operator.
Meanwhile, I would like to call it without the dot operator, such that no warning is thrown (and I don't want to disable warning feature). Is it possible ?

This is my test code :

implicit.scala

```
implicit class IntegerUtils(wrapped:Int) {
    def !() = (2 to wrapped).product
}

(1 to 5).foreach { v => println (v.!) }
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Also note that you could use `i to k by -1` instead of `i.to(k, -1)`

Comment: also note that there is no need in `by -1` here: use `2 to wrapped`. Also note that there is method `product` in scala collections: `(2 to 4).product` => `24`, so you don't need to use `fold` here.

Comment: Ouch. Yes you're right, product method is better (as I am just learning Scala for now, I did not take the time to explore the Range documentation). Again you're right for the use of (2 to 4) in this order, as I am using a multiplication. I've edited the code. Thanks

Comment: @senia I figured `(2 to wrapped).product` would fail for 1, but it turns out that it works. `(2 to 1)` is an empty range, and the product of an empty collection is, apparently, 1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just [`import language.postfixOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.language$):

```
import language.postfixOps
implicit class IntegerUtils(wrapped:Int) {
  def !() = (2 to wrapped).product
}

(1 to 5).foreach { v => println (v!) }            //> 1
                                                  //| 2
                                                  //| 6
                                                  //| 24
                                                  //| 120
```

As the docs note, "Postfix operators interact poorly with semicolon inference. Most programmers avoid them for this reason." But if you're doing a lot of this in a particular file, it can be very handy.